# Check if a function exists or not in PHP

Tags: php

I wants to check if a function exists or not. I am using function_exists() to check.

```
$func = $_GET['function'];
$func();
if(function_exists('func'))
{
    echo "Exists";
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid Function name called";
}
```

Okay now I have a function called `register`, and I am calling it like this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?function=register
```

Okay, it is working fine, because that function does exist.
But if,

```
www.example.com/index.php?function=registerssss
```

It gives me this error:

> Call to undefined function registerssss()

I want to print my custom error as I have posted above. Is there a solution?

Comment: call only if exist

Comment: Whatever problem it is you're trying to solve here, don't solve it like this. It just promotes a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. I modified your code so it will work:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['function']) && function_exists($_GET['function'])) {
    $func = $_GET['function']; // Set the URL variable to a regular PHP var
    $func();                   // Do the function
    echo "Exists and ran";     // Let the user know the function exists and it was ran
  } 
  else {
    echo "Invalid function name called"; // Function does not exists, so output custom error message
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling the function before checking if it exists...

```
$func = $_GET['function'];

if (function_exists($func)) {
    echo "Exists";
    $func();
} else {
    echo "Invalid Function name called";
}
```

Comment: Okay ! you are righyt, but idk what but now when I change my www.example.com/index.php?function=register it pushes my to else part, Yes, the function register do exists!

Comment: register is part of a class? the function is included in this file?

Answer (score 4):

`function_exists` is not the right tool for the job here. What's to prevent a user from executing any built-in function just by appending it to the URL?

Instead use a switch and include only the functions you have defined and want to allow the user to execute:

```
switch ($_GET['function']) {
    case 'function1':
        function1();
        break;
    case 'function2':
        function2();
        break;
    case 'function3':
        function3();
        break;
    default:
        trigger_error("Invalid function");
}
```

Or you could instead use an array, like this:

```
$allowed_functions = ['function1', 'function2', 'function3'];

if (!empty($_GET['function']) && in_array($_GET['function'], $allowed_functions)) {
    call_user_func($_GET['function']);
}
else {
    trigger_error("Invalid function");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Web address for `$_GET`

```
index.php?function=rrr ***FALSE***

index.php?function=test ***TRUE***
```

This works fine below:

```
function test() {
    echo "test";
}

$foo = $_GET['function'];

// Check $_GET has data and function exists 
if (isset($_GET['function']) && function_exists($foo)) {
    echo "True";
} else {
    echo "False";
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Why does it work? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39876004/edit), not here in comments.